# How to find the object that's next to another object in an array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Say I have `objectA` which is inside an array: `[ { name: 'ObjectA'}, { name: 'ObjectB'}, { name: 'ObjectC' } ]`

How do I find the object that's next to `ObjectA` (e.g. `ObjectB`)?

(I can be in vanilla JavaScript or Lodash.)

Comment: `array[INDEX_OF_objectA+1]`

Comment: Is this assuming that the only variable you have is a reference to `ObjectA`? If so, I don't think this is possible, you'd need a reference to the array as well

Comment: Do you need to find this object by one of its values first, or can you simply access the item in the array directly as the commenter above stated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'ObjectA'
}, {
  name: 'ObjectB'
}, {
  name: 'ObjectC'
}];

var nxt = arr.reduce(function(a, b){
   return (a.name === 'ObjectA') ? b : a;
});

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nxt, 0 , 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Try giving "ObjectB" it will return "ObjectA" instead of "ObjectC"

Comment: Yes that is what i returned `: a` which is previous value.

Comment: I believe the ask is to provide next value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the next object, given the name of the current object, try this.

```js
var getNextObject = function(arr,name){
  var currIndex = - 1;
  arr.forEach((i,index)=>{
    if(i.name === name){
      currIndex = index;
    };
  });
  if(currIndex < (arr.length - 1 && currIndex >=0)){
      return arr[currIndex+1];
    }
  //return null if its the last element or the object with such name does not exist in the array
  return null;
}


var arr = [ { name: 'ObjectA'}, { name: 'ObjectB'}, { name: 'ObjectC' } ];


//Most of the code from here on is for demonstration purposes
//
// This function call is good enough ==>  getNextObject(arr,'ObjectA');
// 

var nextOfObjectA = getNextObject(arr,'ObjectA');
var myprea = document.getElementById('newprea');

if(nextOfObjectA && nextOfObjectA.name){
   myprea.innerHTML = nextOfObjectA.name;
}else{
    myprea.innerHTML = 'does not exist';
}

var nextOfObjectC = getNextObject(arr,'ObjectC');
var myprec = document.getElementById('newprec');


//Object C is the last element, hence the function returns null
if(nextOfObjectC && nextOfObjectC.name){
   myprec.innerHTML = nextOfObjectC.name;
}else{
    myprec.innerHTML = 'does not exist';
}
```

```html
<br/>
<p> Next Object for objectA = <span id="newprea"></span> </p>

<br/>
<p> Next Object for objectC = <span id="newprec"></span> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find index of the object (using findIndex) and then get the next item.

```js
var objArr = [ { name: 'ObjectA'}, { name: 'ObjectB'}, { name: 'ObjectC' } ];

var nextObj = objArr[objArr.findIndex(function(item, index) { return item.name == this;}, 'ObjectA')+1];

alert(JSON.stringify(nextObj));

console.log(nextObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var arr = [ { name: 'ObjectA'}, { name: 'ObjectB'}, { name: 'ObjectC' } ];
var objIndex = -1;
arr.forEach( function(value, index){ if ( value.name == "ObjectA" ){ objIndex = index + 1; } } );
console.log( arr[objIndex].name );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getNextOrDefault (name){
//Fetch index of item.
var index = _.findIndex(ary,function(item){  
                             return item.name === name; 
                             });
 //If item found (!==-1) and has next  item (item's index + 1 > length of array)
 return (index !== -1 ? index++ : index) > ary.length || index === -1 
        //Return default
        ? null 
        //Return next item
        : ary[index] ;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k4dgnzpf/

Hope this helps !